# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el comando "tar" actúe sobre los ficheros listados en un fichero?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tar

Estoy haciendo un pequeño script para un trabajo, el cual se encarga de hacer copias de seguridad, y me he quedado en la parte de ampliación. Este sería el código (tiene errores, pero ya han estado corregidos, esto es solo para hacernos una idea de lo que necesito)

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Iniciant la còpia de seguretat incremental de /home "+`date`
echo "Iniciant la còpia de seguretat incrememntal de /home_"+`date +%d%m%Y%H:%M:%S` >> /backup/log/backup_log.log

tar -cpvzf "incrementalbackup_`date +%d%m%Y%H:%M:%S`.tgz" -g /backup/historial/backup.snap /home/

if [$? -eq 0]
    then
        echo "Còpia de seguretat incremental de /home_"+`date +%d%m%Y%H:%M:%S`+" Realitzada correctament "+$? >> /backup/log/backup_log.log
        echo "Backup incremental realitzat correctament, consulta /backup/log/backup_log.log per a més informació"
    else
        echo "La còpia de seguretat incremental de /home_"+`date +%d%m%Y%H:%M:%S`+" Ha sofert errors. "+$? >> /backup/log/backup_log.log
        echo "No s'ha pogut completar el backup incremental, consulta /backup/log/backup_log.log per a més informació"
fi
```

Lo que necesito es que en vez de que el backup se haga del directorio /home, se haga de los directorios escritos en un .txt externo, el cual el usuario puede modificar cuando quiera para especificar diversos directorios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener el listado desde un fichero lo que necesitas es la opción `-T` que aparece en `man tar`:

> **-T, --files-from FILE**
>   get names to extract or create from FILE

Es decir:

> **-T, --files-from FILE**
>   toma los nombres a extraer o crear desde FILE

Así, en tu caso dirías:

```
tar -cpvzf "incrementalbackup_X.tgz" -T tufichero.txt -g /backup/historial/backup.snap /home/
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Nótese por cierto que tu script tiene algún error:

- Al decir `if [$? -eq 0]` necesitas poner un espacio alrededor de `[`.
- Usar `echo "Còpia de seguretat (...) Realitzada correctament "+$?`, pero para ese entonces `$?` ya no tiene el valor inicial que ya comprobaste en el `if`, sino el resultante del `if`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$ ls asdasd
ls: cannot access 'asdasd': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

El valor de `$?` es 2.

```
$ ls asdasd
ls: cannot access 'asdasd': No such file or directory
$ if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "ok $?"; else echo "baaa $?"; fi
baaa 1
```

Por contra, al haber "pasado" por el `if`, `$?` ahora vale lo que devolvió esa evaluación. Por tanto, guarda `$?` para luego evaluarlo e imprimirlo sin problemas de este tipo.

Además:

- En lugar de usar `date +%d%m%Y%H:%M:%S` todo el rato, ¿por qué no lo guardas en una variable para reutilizarlo después?

Comment: Muchas gracias! Efectivamente, mi script contiene errores, lo comenté en el thread. Agradezco mucho tus recomendaciones y la ayuda brindada, ahora mismo me pongo a ello! No sabía lo del valor con el if, muchas gracias por la aclaración.